# predict in R gives wrong number of predictions

Tags: r

I split my data set into 2 data frames: train (having 830 rows) and test (200 rows).  The column names are identical and in the same order.

I built a natural spline model to predict strength on a single variable, cement.

When I try to use that model to make predictions on my test set, instead of getting the expected 200 predictions, I get 830 predictions.  I don't know why this is happening.  I've been through the help pages and the web, but I haven't found anything that fixes this problem.

I have checked the dimensions of test$cement and it does have only 200 entries.

Here is my code right now:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(splines)

attach(train)
fit1 <- lm(strength~ns(cement, 4), data = train)
summary(fit1)
pred1 <- predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(test$cement), se=T)
pred1
detach(train)
```

I've also tried these predict versions:

pred2 <- fit1 %>% predict(test$cement)

--> which gives me errors saying it doesn't understand %>%

pred = predict.bSpline(fit1, newdata = test$cement, se=T)

and

pred = predict.bSpline2(fit1, newdata = test$cement, se=T)

--> Both of which tell me they cannot find the function predict.bSpline or predict.bSpline2, although I opened up both the splines and the splines2 libraries.

Also predict.ns doesn't seem to exist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `newdata` should have the same name as the predictors in the model, so try `newdata = data.frame(cement=test$cement)` . and pleasdon't use `attach` as this can cause a bunch of problems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your data but you should try passing whole dataframe test:

```
pred1 <- predict(fit1, newdata = test, se=T)
```

also "**%>%**" operator is defined in **"tidyr"** library I believe.

*I think that predict.ns predict.bSpline override predict function - look up it's documentation. Although I've never used spline objects what I've read suggests that you just use object type from this library with normal "predict" function.*

Answer (score 1):

I think we would need to see a repoducible example of your data set because I think that might be causing your issue. When I use the following code I get the proper results:

```
library(dplyr)
library(splines)

train <- sample_frac(mtcars, .8)

test <- setdiff(mtcars, train)

fit1 <- lm(mpg~ns(wt, 4), data = train)

pred1 <- predict(fit1, newdata = test, se=T)

pred1
```

Just thinking about `caret` I would make sure that you are not creating a list object when you are creating your train/test splits (`createDataPartition(list = FALSE)`)

Additionally, I would not use `attach`. IT is a little more typing to write out all the variable names, but you can sometimes get odd results which might be what is happening to you. I would restart your R session, remove the attach and then try again.

Not the best solution, but I would give it a go.